# Find specifications by pattern in scala specs2

Tags: scala, sbt, integration-testing, specs2

We have an issue with different environments for our integration tests and start/stop latency.

So, we want to run all environment dependencies before all integration tests and shut down after all.
We can't just use docker since we use GuiceApplication (starts from the code), EmbeddedKafka (starts from the code), and WireMock(starts from the code). :)

We use scala as a main language and Specs2 as testing library. I've found that we can create one spec, add before/after all code to set up env, and override the `is` method, which represents the test. We can join a few other Specs into one by

```
override def is = Seq(new First, new Second)
  .map(_.is)
  .foldLeft(Fragments.empty) { case (l, r) => l.append(r.fragments)}
```

But I want to automatically gather specs into `is.` I see a `SpecificationFinder` trait with methods such as `findSpecifications` and `specifications,` but I can't make them return a non-empty list. We have a root directory called 'integrations,' where we store all needed Specs.

Maybe someone has already implemented the search over tests. It looks like these methods are used during the sbt test task, but I didn't find a way to reuse it as I want

Comment: Which specs2 version are you using? specs2-5.x has a different solution to that problem than specs2-4.x

Comment: Before I write a more comprehensive answer here is an example using specs2 4.x: https://github.com/etorreborre/specs2-integration-tests-4.x and the way it is now done with specs2-5.x: https://github.com/etorreborre/specs2/commit/1e23edcd38e17a3db0128ab9c0a0cefe171df48c

Comment: It worked.
Still have some issues in a combination of mutual spec and immutable - it looks like the order of the steps is not the same. 
But I can run an example. 
Thanks

Comment: Great, I posted a more complete answer. Please create an issue on the github site if you think there is a potential bug with some execution order.

Answer (score 1):

There are two answers to that questions depending on the specs2 version that you are using.

**specs2-4.x** (full example [here](https://github.com/etorreborre/specs2-integration-tests-4.x))

With this version you can collect specifications using a `SpecificationsFinder` and aggregate them as one big specification with one `step` before and one `step` after to start and stop shared services:

```scala
import org.specs2._
import org.specs2.specification.core._
import org.specs2.control._
import org.specs2.io._
import runner._
import user.integration.database._

class IntegrationSpec extends Specification { def is = sequential ^ s2"""
  ${step(db.start)}

  Integration specifications
  $integration

  ${step(db.shutdown)}
"""

  def integration =
    Fragments.foreach(specifications) { specification =>
s2"""
  ${specification.is.header.name} ${specification.is.fragments}
  $p
"""
  }

  val specifications: List[SpecificationStructure] = SpecificationsFinder.findSpecifications(
    // change this pattern if the specifications must be found in specific directories, or with specific names
    glob = "**/*.scala",
    // this pattern detects the name of a specification class inside a scala file
    pattern = "(.*Spec)\\s*extends\\s*.*",
    // this additional filter can be used to filter specifications names
    // in this case we avoid infinite recursive execution
    filter = { (name: String) => !name.endsWith("IntegrationSpec") },
    // this is the base directory where specifications must be searched
    basePath = DirectoryPath.unsafe(new java.io.File("src/test/scala").getAbsolutePath),
    verbose = true).runOption.getOrElse(Nil)

}
```

**specs2-5.x** (full example [here](https://github.com/etorreborre/specs2/commit/1e23edcd38e17a3db0128ab9c0a0cefe171df48c))

With more recent version of specs2 a notion of "global resource" has been introduced so that each individual specification can extend a `Resource[R]` trait (where `R` is a global resource, here is an example with a `Database`):

```scala
trait StartDatabase(using ec: ExecutionContext) extends Resource[Database]:
  override def resourceKey: Option[String] =
    Some("shared database")

  def acquire: Future[Database] =
    Future.successful(Database().start)

  def release(db: Database): Execution =
    Future { db.shutdown; true }
```

and in that case the `steps` used in the previous `IntegrationSpec` are not necessary anymore.